# Get Records of two tables with same date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am stuck in a problem. After trying for hours I could not get to a proper solution.

So first What am I trying to do:
I have two tables of sales and purchase both have data according to dates.

---

**Data is like this in mysql:**
**Sale:**

```
  sale1  |  25-07-14  | 2500
  sale2  |  26-07-14  | 2200
  sale3  |  27-07-14  | 0
  sale4  |  27-07-14  | 1500
  sale5  |  28-07-14  | 1000
```

**Purchase:**

```
  purchase1  |  25-07-14  | 0
  purchase2  |  26-07-14  | 1000
  purchase3  |  27-07-14  | 2500
  purchase4  |  28-07-14  | 0
  purchase5  |  28-07-14  | 100
```

---

**Now I want to show my data like this:**

```
Date| sale(sum)  | purchase(sum)
Date| sale(sum)  | purchase(sum)
Date| sale(sum)  | purchase(sum)
Date| sale(sum)  | purchase(sum)
```

I want data with respect to date from both table.

**this is what I have tried:**

```
SELECT date, sum(purchase_remaining) as a FROM purchase group by date
UNION
SELECT sale_date, sum(sale_balance) as b FROM sale group by sale_date
```

**Result of this query:**

```
date | purchase
date | purchase
date | purchase
date | sale
date | sale
date | sale
```

Any idea how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you setup a SQLFiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: instead of union, you can use two different queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the tables.

```
select date, sum(purchase_remaining) a
, sum(sale_balance) b

from purchase join sale on purchase.date = sale.date
group by date
```

Comment: oh it was sale.sale_date sorry for late selection